# CSS Z-index child above parent and div under parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

Goodday,

I have a setup of 2 div's like this

```
<div id="parent">
     <div id=child"><div>
</div>
<div id="underdiv"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent { position: fixed; z-index: -1; width: 100%; height: 100%;  } 
#child { position: fixed; z-index: 10; width: 300px; height: 300px; }
#underdiv { position: relative; margin-top: 100%; z-index: 9;}
```

So what is want is de #parent fullscreen and when i scroll the underdiv comes over the parent. But the child is visible over the underdiv. Is this possible? It works when i put the #child outside the #parent, but this is not what i want.

demo: http://dailycms.develop.tvtweb.nl/profielpagina.html

Comment: you are already achieving that .. So what is the issue ??

Comment: I think the right solution is already pretty much implemented in your site..  the child element should be inside the #underdiv with negative offset if needed to be on top of the first.. structurally it's more correct since the elements ends up as a part of the #underdiv, is it not?

Comment: #parent { position: fixed; z-index: 10; width: 100%; height: 100%;  } 
#child { position: fixed; z-index: -1; width: 300px; height: 300px; }

Comment: you didn't apply z-index for child div it doesn't takes . apply z-index for parent div and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible. `z-index` is only applicable when two elements are on the same level in the DOM tree (i.e. they have the same parent element).

You can find more details regarding this in [this article](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/), especially in the **Stacking Contexts** part in the article.

Also, here's a link to [MDN's page on Stacking Context in z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: who said that ? any sources ?

Comment: this is true.. more clearly in this case: if you have 2 siblings, with sibling 1 z-indexed above sibling 2, you can't have sibling's 2 child z-indexed above sibling 1...

Comment: @SyedQarib: I've added a few links to different articles about `Stacking Contexts` to support my answer.